# Rails - Simple Form - style error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to make a partial in my views folder, which his shared for error messages.

I want to remove the simple form standard error message and replace it with my own styling - across all models.

My question is, how do I reference the relevant model in my partial. Depending on where its used, it needs to reference the form in which the partial is included.

For example, the standard simple form error block is:

```
<% if @question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project_question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being
        saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @project_question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

How do I replace @question, with @[whatever the relevant model is called]?

Thank you

Comment: you can pass it through `locals` into the partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can make a partial **_error_messages,html.erb**

```
<% if model.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(model.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
       this from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>    
<% end %>
```

And you can render this partial in your view as:

```
<%= render partial: "error_messages", locals: {model: @question} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is a `passing a local variable` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

`<%= render partial: "your_partial", locals: {question: @question} %>`